# Transform std::pair to std::tuple with any number of elements

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, stdtuple

I need the following meta code adapted from `std::pair` to `std::tuple` with any number of elements. I don't want to implement it separately for every possible number of elements.

```
template<typename A, typename B>
struct merge_pairs
{       typedef std::pair<
            decltype(typename A::first() + typename B::first()),
            decltype(typename A::second() + typename B::second())
        > type;
};
```

Comment: you can use variadic template. google it.

Comment: You should provide a **complete** but minimal example exemplifying the desired behavior. It's OK if it doesn't compile as long as the part that doesn't compile is the one you don't have. Make sure that otherwise it's perfect. :)

Comment: Your question probably got closed because it shows none of your efforts to solve the problem. Right now it's a "do my job for me" question. What did you try, and where did you get stuck ?

Comment: @Alf -- the example implementation was always there (merge_pairs).

Comment: @Alf -- I knew that I can use variadic templates. But I don't know how. This is what stackoverflow.com is for, isn't it?

Comment: @Quentin -- no it got closed by "moderators", who did not understand it. They should have simply left the question alone. If I remember correctly the question got 5 upvotes before it got closed. But what does a good dictator care about other peoples opinions....

Comment: @ExcessPhase On what basis do you believe that your question being downvoted and/or closed is due to people not understanding it ? That's not how SO works, and there is no conspiracy against you. But a question without research effort and an aggressive introductory paragraph is definitely going to gather negative feedback.

Comment: @Quentin the answer to your question is obvious. My discussion regarding this was deleted on meta.stackoverflow.com. But there was another discussion on meta.stackoverflow.com -- mine was labeled as a duplicate of this one: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late/252077

Comment: @Quentin: If you do not like my introduction, why don't you do your best, that "moderators" leave questions alone if they do not understand them. Again -- my question got 5 positive votes before getting deleted!

Comment: @ExcessPhase I have not seen your previous question, and have nothing to do with this. But questions are not the place to argue or foment a revolution, and they should be properly formed. That's just SO's quality standard here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109844/discussion-between-excessphase-and-quentin).

Comment: @Quentin I already solved the question before I asked it here for the second time -- but this does not matter. Sharing questions and answers is what stackoverflow.com is all about. So I don't understand your comment regarding doing research myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Option #1

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>

template <typename A, typename B>
struct merge_tuples
{
    static_assert(std::tuple_size<A>::value == std::tuple_size<B>::value, "!");

    template <std::size_t... Is>
    static auto merge(std::index_sequence<Is...>) noexcept
        -> std::tuple<typename std::decay<decltype(std::declval<typename std::tuple_element<Is, A>::type>()
                                                 + std::declval<typename std::tuple_element<Is, B>::type>())
                               >::type...>;

    using type = decltype(merge(std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<A>::value>{}));    
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/771e8f0cab7d2392)

#### Option #2

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename A, typename B>
struct merge_tuples;

template <template <typename...> class Tuple, typename... Ts, typename... Us>
struct merge_tuples<Tuple<Ts...>, Tuple<Us...>>
{
    static_assert(sizeof...(Ts) == sizeof...(Us), "!");

    using type = Tuple<typename std::decay<decltype(std::declval<Ts>()
                                                  + std::declval<Us>())
                                >::type...>;
};
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e2d354e0f92311a)

Comment: What is the static_assert in the second example for?

Comment: @ExcessPhase the number of elements of both variadic packs should be equal

Comment: Example 1 is using a function which is not implemented, right? Cute!

Comment: @ExcessPhase yes, using a function (that offers template type deduction out of the box) is often more concise than introducing a primary template and then providing a specialization. Since the function is used in an unevaluated context (inside `decltype`), you don't need a body